# SQLite query is not taking arguments correctly

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to do an SQLite query in my Android app, but for some reason it doesn't get the arguments correctly. If I hard-code the values, the query works just fine, so I know the overall query is correct and the data is there.

```
...
public String[][] traerEncuestaPostventa(int idBien,
    int idEncuesta)
{

    String[][] arrayDatos = null;

    String[] arrayArgumentos = {String.valueOf(idBien), String.valueOf(idEncuesta), String.valueOf(idBien)};

    Cursor cursor = null;

    cursor = querySQL("SELECT " +
        "encuestadetalle.id_encuestadetalle," +
        "IFNULL(encuestapostventa.id_encuestapostventa, 0) as id_encuestapostventa," +
        "encuestadetalle.zona_inmueble," +
        "encuestadetalle.tarea," +
        "IFNULL(encuestaobservacion.id_encuestaobservacion, 0) as id_encuestaobservacion," +
        "IFNULL(encuestaobservacion.observacion, '') as observacion," +
        "encuestadetalle.id_encuesta," +
        "IFNULL(encuestapostventa.recepcion, 0) as recepcion" +
        " FROM encuestadetalle" +
        " LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM encuestapostventa WHERE id_bien = ?) AS encuestapostventa" +
        " ON encuestadetalle.id_encuestadetalle = encuestapostventa.id_encuestadetalle" +
        " LEFT JOIN encuestaobservacion" +
        " ON encuestapostventa.id_encuestapostventa = encuestaobservacion.id_encuestapostventa" +
        " WHERE encuestadetalle.id_encuesta = ?" +
        " AND (IFNULL(encuestapostventa.id_bien, 0) IN (?, 0))" +
        " ORDER BY encuestadetalle.zona_inmueble, encuestadetalle.tarea", arrayArgumentos);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        arrayDatos = new String[cursor.getCount()][5];

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            //Here I handle the data;

            i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
    CloseDB();
    return(arrayDatos);
}

...

public Cursor querySQL(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    Cursor oRet = null;
    // Opens the database object in "write" mode.
    db = oDB.getReadableDatabase();
    oRet = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
    return(oRet);
}
...
```

Now if I replace the query like this, it works:

```
    cursor = querySQL("SELECT " +
        "encuestadetalle.id_encuestadetalle," +
        "IFNULL(encuestapostventa.id_encuestapostventa, 0) as id_encuestapostventa," +
        "encuestadetalle.zona_inmueble," +
        "encuestadetalle.tarea," +
        "IFNULL(encuestaobservacion.id_encuestaobservacion, 0) as id_encuestaobservacion," +
        "IFNULL(encuestaobservacion.observacion, '') as observacion," +
        "encuestadetalle.id_encuesta," +
        "IFNULL(encuestapostventa.recepcion, 0) as recepcion" +
        " FROM encuestadetalle" +
        " LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM encuestapostventa WHERE id_bien = 5813) AS encuestapostventa" +
        " ON encuestadetalle.id_encuestadetalle = encuestapostventa.id_encuestadetalle" +
        " LEFT JOIN encuestaobservacion" +
        " ON encuestapostventa.id_encuestapostventa = encuestaobservacion.id_encuestapostventa" +
        " WHERE encuestadetalle.id_encuesta = 3" +
        " AND (IFNULL(encuestapostventa.id_bien, 0) IN (5813, 0))" +
        " ORDER BY encuestadetalle.zona_inmueble, encuestadetalle.tarea", null);
```

I also tried replacing the elements in `arrayArgumentos`, but it didn't work, either:

```
    String[] arrayArgumentos = {String.valueOf(5813), String.valueOf(3), String.valueOf(5813)};
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that my array is a String[] and the arguments themselves are integers. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] arrayArgumentos = {String.valueOf(idBien)};

    Cursor cursor = null;

String sql="SELECT " +
        "encuestadetalle.id_encuestadetalle," +
        "IFNULL(encuestapostventa.id_encuestapostventa, 0) as id_encuestapostventa," +
        "encuestadetalle.zona_inmueble," +
        "encuestadetalle.tarea," +
        "IFNULL(encuestaobservacion.id_encuestaobservacion, 0) as id_encuestaobservacion," +
        "IFNULL(encuestaobservacion.observacion, '') as observacion," +
        "encuestadetalle.id_encuesta," +
        "IFNULL(encuestapostventa.recepcion, 0) as recepcion" +
        " FROM encuestadetalle" +
        " LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM encuestapostventa WHERE id_bien ="+String.valueOf(idBien)+ ") AS encuestapostventa" +
        " ON encuestadetalle.id_encuestadetalle = encuestapostventa.id_encuestadetalle" +
        " LEFT JOIN encuestaobservacion" +
        " ON encuestapostventa.id_encuestapostventa = encuestaobservacion.id_encuestapostventa" +
        " WHERE encuestadetalle.id_encuesta ="+String.valueOf(idEncuesta)+"" +
        " AND (IFNULL(encuestapostventa.id_bien, 0) IN (?, 0))" +
        " ORDER BY encuestadetalle.zona_inmueble, encuestadetalle.tarea"

cursor = querySQL(sql, arrayArgumentos);

Log.d("For DEBUG", "Sql String -->"+sql)
```

Try to put some of your arguments directly on the query.

Then print your query to check what is being sent to the database with Log statement. 
The problem may be on the arguments. Also remember that when equal to a String in SQL you should use ' ' . Hope this helps.

Comment: Althought your precise suggestion didn't work, it was a good idea to replace the ?s in my query by the actual arguments. I just replaced all of them instead of leaving one for `arrayArgumentos`, and executed the query like `cursor = querySQL(sql, null);`. I can't believe I couldn't come up with this myself. So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The right format to give argument is as

```
rawQuery("SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE name = ? AND id = ?", new String[] {"David", "2"});
```

check is with hardcoded values like

```
...." ORDER BY encuestadetalle.zona_inmueble, encuestadetalle.tarea",  new String[] {"5813", "3","5813"});
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same that I already have? I changed it to this: `" ORDER BY encuestadetalle.zona_inmueble, encuestadetalle.tarea", new String[] {String.valueOf(idBien), String.valueOf(idEncuesta), String.valueOf(idBien)});` and it's still not working. Your answer just suggested a different way to do the same thing I'm already doing.